Blocking method on a JFrame (or JDialog)
I need that my readString method be blocking until user input his text into the TextArea. This is a model of my problem:
public class Consola
{
    private final JDialog dialog;
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private String userInput; 
                                        
    public Consola(JFrame mainFrame)
    {
        dialog=new JDialog(mainFrame);
        textArea=new JTextArea();
        textArea.addKeyListener(new EscuchaKey());
        dialog.add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);

        dialog.setSize(300,300);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String readString() 
    {
        // Resetear el estado
        userInput=null;
        textArea.setText("");
        
        while(userInput==null)
        {
        }
        
        return userInput;
    }

    class EscuchaKey extends KeyAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                userInput=textArea.getText().trim();
            }
        }
    }
}

I konw that the problem where is while(...); but I put it as example.
Here is the main class:
public class ConsolaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Crear un JFrame principal
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test Consola");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(300,300);
        
        JButton button = new JButton(":O)");
        mainFrame.add(button,BorderLayout.WEST);

        Consola consola = new Consola(mainFrame);
        
        // Acción del botón
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            String input = consola.readString();
            System.out.println("Texto ingresado: " + input);
        });

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

What I need is that readString method return the string inputed by the user. The method prototy can not be changed.
To understand the problem you can watch these videos:
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjYxSENnzyZltzpXd2_7azTYRu0QEOZbf&si=m2ZF2tZz3GrN-B81
The first shows the Console class exactly how I want it to work (in fact it works fine).
The second is the same console class but instantiated from another JFrame. The current implementation takes user input via JOptionPane, but I want it to work exactly the same as shown in the first video.
Please, help me. Thank.

Instead of creating your own input dialog, use JOptionPane.showInputDialog, which will block until the user presses the accept button.  For example:  String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame, "Enter text:");

What is a prototy in your second last paragraph? If you can't use the built-in input class, do want a synchronisation Event with which EsuchaKey.keyPress can signal when there is text in the text area? Is your readString method intended to be run on a different thread from the thread that instantiates the Console class and displays the instance?

@VGR isn't possible. What I need is what I show.

@SmellyCat what I need is that readString wait until user input his text into jtextarea. And then return it's text

So it must be a JTextArea, and the readString method must wait for one character to be entered into that JTextArea?  That is not normally how a text input field behaves.

@VGR please see this videos in which I show the problem...
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjYxSENnzyZltzpXd2_7azTYRu0QEOZbf&si=m2ZF2tZz3GrN-B81

@BasilBourque sorry, I don't understand

You look to be trying to create a console application with a Swing GUI. Yes, this can be done, but is in effect trying to force a square peg into a round hole. Rather, instead consider creating a GUI form or dialog forms that accept and validate input in an event-driven fashion.

How do you "know" the user has finished typing text?  Usually, there's a JButton for the user to left-click signifying that the user has, indeed, finished typing text.  That's why a JOptionPane or JDialog has an "OK" JButton.  Put the readString method call in the ActionListener of the JButton.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Based on the video, your Consola class needs provide functions for print and println in addition to readString. Instead of a video, you should provide pseudo code of the expected implementation for Consola.
@VGR suggested a good starting point, but I’d clarify you should use both JTextArea and JOptionPane.

If you want to use a text area as a console, please have a look at MadProgrammer's answer to a similar question here.

“I need that my readString method be blocking until user input his text into the TextArea.”  Blocking until what happens, exactly?  When would such a method unblock?  After the user has typed one character?  After the user has pressed enter?

Hello user3216993 , welcome, this is for you to think about, “if you can't put the effort to write a few lines explaining what you need (watch the video!), I can't put the effort to write a few lines answering”.
